# Possíveis erros de tradução

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Encontrei as seguintes frases mal traduzidas a meu ver [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em vez de `Enviou 10 mensagens no chat, pelo menos 1 com estrela` poderia ser tal como mencionado pelo @Articuno:

> Enviou 10 mensagens no chat, pelo menos 1 favoritada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em vez de `Visitou o site 30/100 por dias consecutivos.` deveria ser:

> Visitou o site por 30/100 dias consecutivos.

Comment: Pra ganhar a medalha conversador, precisa de 10 mensagens enviadas no chat do site, e ao menos uma precisa ser favoritada. A descrição original está correta.

Comment: @Articuno a meu ver dá a entender que tenho de enviar 10 mensagens, dessas 1 tem de ter estrela, mas penso a ideia é que deveria ser 10 enviadas cada uma com pelo menos 1 estrela?

Comment: Não vejo dificuldade de entender, a mensagem diz: *"Enviou 10 mensagens no chat, pelo menos 1 com estrela"*, pelo menos uma das 10 mensagens precisa ter estrela, ou seja, favoritada. Pra mim está bem claro isso.

Comment: @Articuno o meu ingles não é o melhor mas.. `Post 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in chat` https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: Entendo sua confusão, talvez pelo fato de que você não tem costume de frequentar o chat, realmente dá uma margem de entendimento errado essa tradução. Como eu estou habituado, não vejo nada de errado, mas uma sugestão melhor seria: `Enviou 10 mensagens no chat, pelo menos 1 favoritada`

Comment: @Articuno Devo então editar a pergunta e remover essa parte?

Comment: Deixa a sugestão na pergunta, para ver o ponto de vista de outros usuários :)

Comment: IMHO, acho que poderia ser enviou 10 mensagens no chat, com pelo menos 1 marcada com estrela (ou algo semelhante), e visitou o site por 30/100 dias consecutivos. Mas, da maneira que estão são compreensíveis, só que é necessário se esforçar um pouco mais =D...

Comment: @Stormwind acho que só de a pessoa frequentar o chat, ela entende de cara esses descritivos de medalha do chat. O problema é quem nunca participou ou participou pouco, a pessoa não vai entender muito bem o que é essa tal "estrela".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seguindo as sugestões na pergunta e nos comentários apliquei as seguintes modificações no transifex:

> Enviou 10 mensagens no chat, pelo menos 1 favoritada
>
> Visitou o site por 30 dias consecutivos.
>
> Visitou o site por 100 dias consecutivos.

Precisa aguardar que alguém do staff aprove para que vá ao ar

Comment: Muito obrigado, Math! Faz muito tempo que a gente espera por estas traduções.